# Change Tmux default shortcut to switch between sessions

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

The current shortcut is `Prefix )` and `Prefix (` to switch between sessions.

I want to change it to `Ctrl PageUp/PageDown`, but I don't know what command should be executed when I pressed these keys.

I didn't find any command to override these default prefixes.

Comment: Check out superuser.com for questions about general software usage, SO is only for software dev questions. This Q seems to come close: https://superuser.com/questions/680238/making-tmux-use-altnum-to-select-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is `switch-client` with `-n` (next) and `-p` (previous) options.

```
bind -n C-PageUp switch-client -p
bind -n C-PageDown switch-client -n
```

Comment: Perhaps more interesting than what the correct command *is* is how you *discovered* what the command was, given the original shortcuts. Did you, for example, use `tmux list-keys '('` or skim the output of `tmux list-keys` for `(`?

Comment: @chepner I didn't know this. Thanks!